# Hide an empty cart error Agile Web Development With Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was reaserching a way to fix the bug for section 11.4 for the book Agile Web Development With Rails 4, when I did not find the answer after some tests I was able to fix it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I apologize for issuing this as a question but I was not able to find a place where to post this information as I think it is useful.

Please feel free to move this to the proper place is you need to.

Comment: +1 for sharing your information.  Being that Stack Overflow was designed for Question/Answer format, a better way to do this would be posing your question, then posting an answer to your own question.  This preserves Q/A format and prevents "answer sharks" (such as myself) from getting disappointed that a seemingly unanswered question is in fact an answer.  :-)

Comment: @They_Call_Me_Joe Your question contained actually only an answer; I have edited the question and your answer to separate them. Please expand the question about the exact error, because currently, there is only a reference to the book, not the error itself.